# Image processing using Python and OpenCV on a Raspberry PI

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

I am planning on doing image processing with OpenCV and Python on the RPi. The easy of use of the Pi camera with Python (Picamera module) is very tempting. I know that C++ is definitely going to be faster than Python when doing significant processing but there isn't an easy way of accessing the camera.

**Question: What would be the performance hit of using Python for an image processing application as opposed to implementing the same in C++ ?**

My question is mainly focused on the way OpenCV libraries are called from within the cv2 module in Python ? Is there a ton of overhead associated with that?

Comment: This is a valid question and I am not sure why it would be flagged to be closed? Is there are different place where a question such as this should be asked? If so, don't just downgrade the question but suggest why it's not a valid question.

Comment: The standard advice I'd give to anyone prototyping is to write as much as possible in Python then start replacing performance critical sections of the code with c++ when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the computationally expensive stuff can be done in opencv. so using python for the wrapper won't cost you much computationally.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the input. I was not sure if there would be substantial overhead with using Python.

Comment: python's about 10 times slower than c++ , but opencv is the same speed in any language and that's where all the "pixel pushing' occurs,   the python code should just be doing simple tasks like comparing short lists of coordinates and adding numbers.

Comment: Thank you Jasen for explaining that. It makes sense now.

Comment: @Jasen please provide a citation that Python is 10X slower than C++ for any given task. Can't? It's simply not true.